# Round down to the nearest multiple of five c++

Tags: c++, rounding

I have a little problem with the round down.

I would round down the number to the nearest multiple of five.

Here some examples:

```
4 -> 0

67 -> 65

23 -> 20

44 -> 40 

59 -> 55
```

I tried in different ways, but I can't do it.

Is there some method to do it?

Comment: You can show us what you tried and what you got instead

Comment: This is a math problem.  Did you work out the problem on paper first?

Comment: Hint: The modulo operator (`c = a % b`) can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have variables of type *int*, you can employ the fact that dividing them with an other *int* will give you an integer, so that if you multiply again by that number, you 
get what you want.

So:

```
int a = 59;
std::cout << ((a / 5) * 5) << "\n";
```

would output 55.

If the values are not stored as integer, you can cast them before executing the division:

```
float a = 59;
std::cout << ((static_cast<int>(a) / 5) * 5) << "\n";
```

Comment: I believe, although I haven't tried, that you'd be able to do `a -= (a % 5);`

Comment: @SeanBrookins yes, good point, that would work as well. (However it will fail compiling if a is float. If that is a good thing or a bad thing, I guess it's up to debate)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your number is stored in an integer format, you can use integer division for this:

```
int a = 44;
int r = (a/5) * 5; //will round down to 40
```